# Laravelcollective html form errors are not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravelcollective

Error: BadMethodCallException in FormBuilder.php line 1208:
Method hasErrors does not exist.

So I have installed Laravelcollective as usual, and most aspects are working.

My composer.json

```
"laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",
```

And in my config/app.php providers

```
 Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

And aliases

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

However, I am getting the error:

BadMethodCallException in FormBuilder.php line 1208:
Method hasErrors does not exist.

Not too sure what is going on here. My errors in my html look like this.

```
{{ Form::hasErrors('name') }}
{{ Form::errors('name') }}
```

Do i need to install a seperate package for these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because there are no `hasErrors()` and `errors()` methods in Laravel Collective. I've just checked the code of the latest version of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this reference https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html. It has requirements you need to meet before installing the package, you need to check it first also.

Answer (score 0):

is over:

composer dump-autoload -o

php artisan route:clear

php artisan cache:clear

```
    {!! Form::open(['url' => 'AddDataProfileController']) !!}
      {!!Form::text('email', 'E-Mail Address')!!} 
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why those three commands fix the problem? e.g. is optimizing the autoloader necessary? was there something wrong with the current autoloader?